# Implementing nRF52840 as modem only

Tags: bluetooth-low-energy

I do a lot of embedded electronic design with a handful of microcontrollers, and I want to make a variant of an existing product of mine a Bluetooth LE central device so as to talk to some specific peripheral devices. Reading up on this, it seems all the modules are a microcontroller in their own right; not simply a modem. If I want to purchase a module such as [this](https://www.digikey.com.au/en/products/detail/seeed-technology-co-ltd/113990584/9697027), with a J-Link programmer and design my PCB to incorporate this with pins for power, SWD and interface comms (either UART or SPI), is there a Nordic nRF5 SDK that will allow me to do that?

I would like to be able to pair with devices and send serial data back and forth. I don't want to redevelop my existing product to solely use the microcontroller that accompanies the BLE module; but the Nordic Semi documentation appears to assume that.

Comment: Why do you need Nordic specifically? I mean, they do microcontrollers + BLE, but you don't want the microcontroller. Furthermore, the nRF52840 is kinda the flagship controller in the nRF52-series, sounds a bit wasteful.

Comment: I certainly don't need most of the features of the nRF52840, but for the ability for it to be 'Central'. It appears most models beneath can only act as a BLE peripheral device. I'm all too happy to just have a chip and an antenna but these modules come pre-approved for a lot of RF compliance, so that would remove some of that headache.

Comment: You need to add BLE-Central to your product; check.  Do you supply the peripherals that will be connecting to it (I.e. you choose and control the BLE-peripheral hardware and software), or is there some specific existing device that you need to support connecting to your BLE-Central? Final question, I see you have chosen a module with a u.Fl connector, do you want an external antenna? (many modules are available with chip or PCB trace antennas)

Comment: You're right @DanielChisholm - the existing product I'm seeking to add BLE to has a aluminium enclosure which rules out a chip or trace antenna. Hoping to put a small external antenna on care of a u.Fl to SMA adapter. I don't make the peripheral devices this device is talking to. I've ordered some parts to do some testing, will see how it goes.

Comment: So are the peripheral devices already programmed to be a UART-to-BLE bridge? What service or protocol are they using? (You'll have to program the Central accordingly, I am wondering if it is already available in the  SDK or as an example somewhere)

Comment: The peripheral devices SDK is only somewhat forthcoming; but it appears to be ordinary serial communication very similar to other products they make that we already interface via CAN or RS485.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Nordic nRF5 SDK will allow you to create your own board and includes libraries that support both programming and peripherals. You will find examples that demonstrate receiving data via a serial wired port or a USB-emulated serial port, and relaying it over the BLE radio link.

All of the nRF52 series support both Central and Peripheral roles. They mainly differ in the amount of RAM and ROM available. Some also support other radio protocols (e.g., ANT), and the newer nRF52 chips support more advanced versions of BLE (5.1, 5.2). The chip datasheet and the SDK documentation online will have the information you need.

Comment: Thanks for that. Will uploading the nRF5 SDK expose the pins I need to have a UART / SPI interface out of the box, or will I need to write a MicroPython program to run on the nRF5 host controller to facilitate external interfacing?

Comment: Yes you do have to write some firmware, and the native language of the SDK is C. But there is a Micropython port here https://github.com/micropython/micropython/tree/master/ports/nrf